# Run function only once in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a function which creates an ID for a div with a random number appended to it for uniqueness. The problem is that I need to be able to run the random number generator only once on component load, otherwise the random number generation runs on every input.

```
const randomID = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
const generateID = text => {
    return text.replace(/\s+/g, '-') + '-' + randomID;
};
```

I've considered using useEffect, but it doesn't seem to be running correct:

```
useEffect(() => {
    const randomID = Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000);
},[]);
```

How can I ensure the randomID number only runs once, guaranteeing the randomID number is only going to run when the component loads and not every time the component loads?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It's ok to use it inside the `useEffect` to make it run only once per component mount, but to use that value you should also have a state to set it and use it in your HTML element. Like this:

```
const [randomID, setRandomID] = useState(null);

useEffect(() => {
    setRandomID(Math.floor(1000 + Math.random() * 9000));
},[]);
```